# How to add row url?

Tags: magento2, grid, url, uicomponent

I have created a **custom UI component grid in admin**. But there is **no link on grid rows**.

How to **add URL to rows in a custom UI component grid in admin**?

Answer (score 0):

**For adding Anchor in uicomponent grid in admin, your column must look like below.**

```
    <column name="order_id" class="Your\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyOrder">
           <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order Id</item>
               </item>
           </argument>
    </column>
```

In Your `Your\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MyOrder` File.

You can get value of that particuler cell in file where You can manipulate value to specific html. like i did below.

```
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class MyOrder extends Column {

    protected $escaper;


    protected $_urlBuilder;
    protected $systemStore;
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $_orderRepo;

    public function __construct(
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder, 
        ContextInterface $context, 
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo,
        Escaper $escaper,
        array $components = [], array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_orderRepo = $orderRepo;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource) {

        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $incrementId = $this->_orderRepo->get($item['order_id'])->getIncrementId();
                $url = $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl("sales/order/view", array('order_id' => $item['order_id']));
                $item['order_id'] = "<a href='" . $url . "' target='_blank' >" . $incrementId . "</a>";
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }

}
```

Comment: I am not talking about the column, I need URL on the row.

Comment: on whole row? @AnshuMishra